# how display for unlogged user output of a relation which haswhere clasue with logged user ID

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, model, eloquent

I have this relation, which contains reference to logged user

```
public function booksdislikedbyUser()
{
return $this->hasMany('Userattitude')->where('creator_id', Auth::user()->id)->selectRaw('count(IF(attitude = -1,0,1)) as dislikedbooks')->groupBy('entity_id');

}
```

My VIEW file which displays the output must be visible both for logged and unlogged user.

Problem: if user is not logged, I receive this error: 
 Trying to get property of non-object

**My question:** what is best practice if I want to get the view and disable(?) the relation?

**Option 1:**
What I am about to do is to put two variants of the code in IF - ELSE brackets.

```
if(Auth::check())
```

It works, but it doesn.t look like a good practice.

**Option 2:** 
in place of

```
->where('creator_id', Auth::user())
```

i would put

```
->where('creator_id', ($user_id ? $user_id : NULL))
```

Where I shoud define the variable then? 
    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with Option 2.

```
public function booksdislikedbyUser()
{
    $userId = (Auth::user() ? Auth::user()->id : null);
    return $this->hasMany('Userattitude')->where('creator_id', $userId)->selectRaw('count(IF(attitude = -1,0,1)) as dislikedbooks')->groupBy('entity_id');
}
```

Or even simpler, use the `Auth::id()` function:

```
return $this->hasMany('Userattitude')->where('creator_id', Auth::id())->selectRaw('count(IF(attitude = -1,0,1)) as dislikedbooks')->groupBy('entity_id');
```